# How do I scroll to the top of a window using applescript?

Tags: applescript, scroll

I want applescript to scroll a window all the way up.

I've tried the page up key, the home key, and I've tried looking for a way to scroll using the built in scrolling capabilities of the window, but I've so far been unable to even move the scrolled position at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, use a `tell app "System Events"` statement to send keystrokes and key codes.
In theory, you could use the following:

```
keystroke page up key
keystroke page down key
keystroke home key
```

But for me this doesn´t work. The good news is that you can use the key codes instead. I suggest using the excellent free [Full Key Codes](http://softwares.bajram.com/utilities/#Full_Key_Codes) application to read them, though it is a bit tricky to let it read two keys pressed simultaneously.

The key codes for the <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>arrow keys</kbd>-combos are as following:

Page up: <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>up key</kbd>: `key code 116`

Page down: <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>down key</kbd>: `key code 121`

Home: <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>left key</kbd>: `key code 115`

End: <kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>right key</kbd>: `key code 119`

So for example if you had a long page open in Safari, and you want to scroll to its end, use

```
tell application "System Events"
tell application "Safari" to activate
    — to see the animation, we wait a moment:
    delay 0.5  

    key code 119

end tell
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. I tried a lot of things, many of which were similar to your solution, but they weren't quite right. This works like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately, the referenced keyboard utility is obsolete (written for the PowerPC platform). **Key Code** (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) is an alternative that is still being maintained (and is also free).

Answer (score 4):

With browsers you could also use JavaScript:

```
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
    do JavaScript "window.scroll(0,0)"
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1
    execute javascript "window.scroll(0,0)"
end tell
```

Comment: While this only works for the two browser apps stated, it has two advantages: it is more robust than the keystroke-sending approach, and it doesn't require authorization for assistive access, unlike the GUI scripting approach.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to sending keystrokes is to use [**GUI scripting**](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/).

**Caveat**: While GUI scripting is **more robust** than sending keystrokes for a *given version* of an application, changes in the application's layout in **future versions can break your code**.

Also:

- GUI scripting requires that **access for assistive devices** be enabled; enabling requires admin privileges:

  - up to 10.8, this could be done *programmatically*, *system-wide* by executing `tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true` (required admin privileges)
  - Sadly, on 10.9+, this no longer works, and apps must be authorized *manually, individually* - the system will prompt you on first run (requires admin privileges)
  - however, in both scenarios `tell application "System Events" to get UI elements enabled` will *report* whether access is enabled or not.
- **Determining the right UI element targets can be non-trivial and tedious**; using the `Accessibility Inspector` utility that comes with `Xcode` helps. The class names reported by this utility correspond to the `UI element` classes contained in the `System Events` dictionary; e.g., `AXSplitGroup` corresponds to `splitter group`.

The following scrolls `Safari 6.0.3`'s front window to the top (access for assistive devices must be enabled):

```
tell application "System Events"

    # Use Accessibility Inspector to find the desired target.
    tell front window of process "Safari"
        tell scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of last group
            set value of attribute "AXValue" to 0  # Scroll to top.
        end tell
    end tell

end tell
```

**Update**: As a reminder that this type of scripting works well *for a given version of an application*, the code had to be changed for `Safari 8.0.4`:

```
tell application "System Events"

    # Use Accessibility Inspector to find the desired target.
    tell front window of process "Safari"
        tell scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2
            set value of attribute "AXValue" to 0  # Scroll to top.
        end tell
    end tell

end tell
```