# Mac OS X - control other window

Tags: objective-c, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I scroll to the top of a window using applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965730/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-a-window-using-applescript)

I want to control other window of other process on Mac OS X 10.6.

For example, I want to scroll down of Safari.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript can scroll down pages in Safari, check:
[How do I scroll to the top of a window using applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965730/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-a-window-using-applescript)

Script:

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell application "Safari" to activate
   delay 0.5
   key code 119
end tell
```

Simply run this script with NSAppleScript:

```
NSAppleScript *scrollDownSafari = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\"\ntell application \"Safari\" to activate\ndelay 0.5\nkey code 119\nend tell"];
[scrollDownSafari executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

**EDIT**

Better readable code:

```
NSString *script =
@"tell application \"System Events\"\n"
 "tell application \"Safari\" to activate\n"
 "delay 0.5\n"
 "key code 119\n"
 "end tell";

NSAppleScript *scrollDownSafari = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];
[scrollDownSafari executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Comment: You can make that more readable by using string concatenation: `@"ab`"  is equivalent to `@"a" @"b"`.

Comment: I agree :) Note: Only the first line requires the `@`, but you can use the `@` with every line.

Comment: is there any other solution using Objective C?

Comment: Nope. AppleScript is the recommended way to communicate with other applications, especially because it prevents incompatibility problems. For example, AppleScript makes sure your application works with every (future) version of Safari. If you implement your own method, it might brake with the next Safari update. Don't be afraid to use AppleScrip, it's very useful for specific tasks.